# how would i rotate an angle Torus

Tags: mesh

Hi how would i  go by rotate an angle Torus at 45* to revolve around the origin like in gif 1 and not like gif2 ? I would like to do something simulator to this video  thank for your help

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhyT6yUxZq0

Comment: In both of the gifs, your Torus is rotating. Do as Mr Zak suggested and edit your post better explaining what you need/want. Until then few people can help you.

Comment: In gif1 you are rotating on z-axis by pressing `RZ` - in gif2 you are rotating on y-axis by pressing `RY`.

Answer (score 2):

You can limit the movement by locking other axes for rotation. Open the numeric panel (<kbd>N</kbd>, or click on the + sign on the top right of the 3D viewport.

Then lock the rotation for the X and Y axes.

Your object can then rotate on Z axis only.

An alternative without locking the axis is pressing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> on the keyboard, the rotation movement will be restricted to the Z axis.

[image]

Comment: R-Z locks on Z global axis (the world's Z axis), but R-Z-Z locks on local Z axis (object's Z axis, changing with object's rotations in object mode).